# Checking if dataframe column has unicode

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder what is the simplest way to check if a pandas dataframe column has unicode versus just having ascii strings.

I was gonna try `df['fieldname'].str.isascii` but that does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3, `str`s are unicode.

Your code, `df['fieldname'].str.isascii`, returns a Series, which rows of True or False. Since you want to check if the column has at least one `str` value, you can check as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'text': [1, 2, '3'], # '3' is str here.
    }
)

if True in df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.isascii() if isinstance(x, str) else False).to_list():
    print('at least one ascii')
else:
    print('no ascii')
# at least one str -> this will be printed because '3' is ascii.
```

Comment: I actually wanted to distinguish between an ascii string vs a unicode string.

Comment: @paolov Oh, I edited my code so that if there is an aschii string.